# Saving an NSString from an HTTP POST to a text file in an EC2 instance

Tags: objective-c, amazon-ec2, flask

I have an EC2 instance that I want to send data to from my iPhone app. I am having trouble with the server recognizing and saving the data to a text file.

In the Objective-C I have done this:

```
- (void) sendDataToServer:(NSString *)url : (NSString *) content{

    // define your form fields here:
    //NSString *content = @"field1=42&field2=Hello";

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Data=%@",content];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *contentData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

   // NSData *contentData = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:contentData];


    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[contentData length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    //[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    // generates an autoreleased NSURLConnection
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (conn){
        NSLog(@"connection");
        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    //[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               //[self doSomethingWithData:data];
                               NSLog(@"Success!");

                               if (error){
                                   NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
                               }
                           }];

}
```

On my server I have flask working properly. In a .py file I have this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['the_file']
        f.save('#path-to-destination-folder')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I know that there is something wrong with the code in my server. I keep getting an error 400 when I try to send the data to my server.

How do you save an NSString as a text file in a remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.files` contains files that were sent to the server. You are only sending POST data. That can be accessed using `request.form`.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form['Data']
        with open('/path/to/file', 'w') as f:
            f.write(data)

    return 'some response that means ok'
```

You'll probably want to do something a bit more robust than this before writing something to the file system, but it's the general idea of what you need to do.

`Data` may not be the correct key. I don't know Objective-C but it looks like that's what you set it to with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Data=%@",content]`.

Comment: The key may not be called `'Data'`. What error do you get in debug mode?

Comment: I got this: <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>

Comment: With debug turned on (in Flask) you should get a full traceback.

Comment: I forgot to change f = to data =, but after I did I get error 500 and this:     raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response

Comment: You just have to make it return something. I've edited the answer to return a string but you can return other types, such as json.